# Naming functions in PHP

Tags: php

I looked online and could not find any answer. I'm new to PHP and i've seen so many different ways of naming functions. Namely,

isset <- no underscore

is_integer <- underscore

fooBar <-subsequent words after the first have the first letter capitalized.

In what way do the functions differ in the way they work, such that they are named differently by convention? Or is it some other reason?

Comment: It depended on how much beer the early php developers had been drinking that day.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier versions of PHP built-in functions had no naming conventions, that's why we have such a zoo. But, no, it does not matter how you name a function as long as you use naming conventions of your team.

If you're making shared public code/library you better stay close to, for example, http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/ PHP standards

Comment: Thank you! It was giving me a headache trying to discern the differences

Comment: Part of the problem came from when PHP and Zend joined forces. Each had their own naming convention, and instead of normalizing to one or the other they just got kind smooshed together. IIRC there was an RFC to address this, but I wouldn't hold my breath because backwards compatibility.